# Convert inherited T2 object from T1 in generic?

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop, inheritance

The problem is:

```
public class Entity {...}

public class Item : Entity {...}

...

List<Entity> EntityList = new List<Entity>();

List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>();

EntityList.Add(ItemList[0]); //ItemList contains some object Item
```

Now `EntityList[0]` contains `Item` object, but it have `Entity` as `.GetType`, and have no any `Item` properties, becouse it "Converts" object. Is there any `method` which can "convert" from Entity back to `Item`?

I also want to know: is object destroys when you add it to list with parent class type, and then rebuilds into parents type object?

Comment: Well, you need to cast the items, but there's a larger problem here with your architecture. Any time you are doing this almost certainly means your code structure is poorly designed and should be reworked.

Comment: The object referenced by `ItemList[0]` is the exact object referenced by `EntityList[0]`.  
It's only the reference that has a different type.  

This is known as [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) - the ability to use a reference of a parent type to point to an instance of a child type.

Comment: There's also a LINQ extension method (`using System.Linq`) that can be used to filter items by type: `EntityList.OfType<Item>()`.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is destroyed or rebuilt, it's all about references and the type of your variables.

You can save a `Cow` in a `List<Animal>`, but so can a `Monkey` and a `Bear`. The items you'll get back from the list's enumerator will have the type declared on the list, in this case `Animal` or in your case `Entity`.

You'll have to cast and test for each possibility:

```
foreach (var entity in EntityList)
{
    if (entity is Item i)
    {
        // do something with i
    }
    if (entity is AnotherType a)
    {
        // do something with a
    }
}
```

But you use a list of base types when you want to treat the entire contents of the list the same. For example, because you want to call `Animal.Eat()` on all of them, and you don't care how the animal eats.

So the actual problem you have, is that you have a list of `Entity` while you're not actually interested in `Entity`, but in `Item`.